# Return an object that respects the arguments suggested in the function

Tags: typescript

I have an `interface User` which defines the following structure:

```
interface User extends Model {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

And I have a function called `select<T extends Model>(... columns: (keyof T)[])` whose `T` can be represented by `User`. In `columns` I can only use one of the `keyof T` arguments (that is, in `User`, it would be `"id"`, `"name"` and/or `"age"`).

I can use it as follows:

```
select<User>("id", "name"); // Works as expected.
select<User>("id", "email"); // Fails as expected ("email" doesn't exists in `User`).
```

As you can see, the rule works perfectly. Both for the case of correct use (using only the `keyof User`) and notifying invalid uses (like using `"email"`, which was never defined in `keyof User`).

However, I need the `return` `type` of this function to be a *partial object* of `T` that only includes the `keyof T` that were also used as an *argument* to the function:

```
const example = select<User>("id", "name");

typeof example === { "id": number, "name": string } // But not includes "age", for instance.
```

That way I could use `example` consistently with the arguments I passed to `select()` in its own definition.

---

**Edit #1:** one of the "quasi-solutions" I got was this way:

```
function select<T extends Model>(... columns: (keyof T)[]): 
    { [Key in keyof T]: string } { ... }
```

When using the following syntax (note the lack of defining the generic `T` as `User`):

```
const user = select('id', 'name');
user.id; // Works as expected.
user.name; // Works as expected.
user.email; // Fails as expected.
```

However, this way the code loses the ability to know that it is about a `User` (as `T`), although it respects the definitions of the names passed as an argument.

So the following code is valid, generates a valid response, but is incompatible with `User`:

```
const user = select('anything');
user.anything; // Works, but not is present on `User`.
```

Which means that if I use a `Pick<User, "id" | "name">` should work, however, I will lose all Typescript versatility, and the calls will be quite redundant:

```
const user = select<Pick<User, "id" | "name">>("id", "name");
```

Comment: You want to return only parameters of function passed in select function right?

Comment: @NeerajKumar In reality, I need the `type` of the `select()` function to respect the arguments received during its call and return an `object` whose keys respect both the arguments received (eg `"id", "name"`) as well as the `T` interface keys (such as `User`). So `select("id", "name")` should return a `type` like `{id: any, name: any}`, even if `User` has other definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you need two generic type parameters. One for the object that you want to enforce keys of, and one for those keys.

With both of those you can then `Pick<T, K>` to get a type of just those keys on that object.

But the problem here is that You have one explicit type parameter (the object type) and one implicit type parameter that you want to infer from usage. However, Typescript requires that all type parameters are explicit, or all implicit. You cannot mix and match them.

So this can't work:

```
declare function select<T extends Model, K extends keyof T>(...keys: K): any
select<User>('id') // Error: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
select<User, 'id'>('id') // works but terribly verbose
```

---

The work around is typically to split up the type parameters into two functions.

```
declare function select<T extends Model>():
  <K extends keyof T>(... columns: K[]) => Pick<T, K>
```

And use it like so:

```
const a = select<User>()("id", "name"); // Works as expected.
//                    ^ call the first function to lock in the <User> type
```

Here you have one function that is intended to be called with an explicit type parameter. That function returns another function that expect the object keys to be inferred from the arguments. By splitting this into two function you can  split up the assignment of the type parameters.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=98&pln=15&pc=56#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeAvgFDGiSyIoCqAztMhAB6Qia1pa4HHJ-LBMALmQgArgFsARtADcvfiDgSII2mCigA5vP7I4W1aMkyo8ksWwIccKChhiQCMMHQhk9HBGcAeACqMLBBsHBjYOAB8ABQAlEIKPgDSgazsyADWEACe6DDIftEAdMXICOg4kiC0IokA2gC6McgAvBHIAArACOn+ADTIiRGkZVVg+i0euN5gPnTQ0TFRAESCS-1LSipLMbLIAPR7yADq6FDpHHAczAAO0xCYhcQHegB6APzDburIUhOe07N6FAFstVusIBI4MAcNtds8AGJQnAXK5MW7Oe7IZYQpFLZCYdAQWggADkY2YwHUHFAyAABnMoLSYoUgA)

---

Although if you can expect an actual object value to infer the object type from, this gets easier:

```
declare function select<
  T extends Model,
  K extends (keyof T)[]
>(
  obj: T,
  ...keys: K
): Pick<T, K[number]>

declare const user: User
const a = select(user, "id", "name"); // Works as expected.
const b = select(user, "id", "email"); // Fails as expected ("email" doesn't exists in `User`).
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeAvgFDGiSyIoCqAztMhAB6Qia1pa4HHJ-LBMALmQgArgFsARtADcvfiDgSII2mCigA5vP7I4W1aMkyo8ksWwIccKChhiQCMMHQhk9HBGcAeBQBVGFgg2DgxsHAAaBQBpINZ2ZAAKAGsIAE90GGR-AEoAbQBdYgA+JIV0KQArEX9ovgA6JrT02hEY4lyRAAVgBBSfOuQY-PFpaEKS0isbO2QEN3VkMXooETpoYgWQJbhkAF4PXG8wJJXoSOQAIkEry6ulFSvc2WQAejfkAHV0KBSOOAcZgABxOEEwDWIHz0AD0APykbZLKQHI5eZxnVb3W73CASODAHDPV7QgBiBJwAKBTFBznBySueIpV2QmHQEFoIAA5GAgsB1BxQMgAAYbKDC3INIA)

Comment: Wow! You pointed out to me that my projection was wrong, in reality. In fact, it doesn't make much sense for a function to define columns of an interface but not do anything with them (which basically made it a "type definer", but in this case it would make much more sense to just use `type`). Indeed `user` (as instance of `User`) must be part of the function call. So it really would be easier to use `Pick` in this case. However, it still seems quite limited to me that Typescript doesn't allow doing it like before (although, at least for this case, it really doesn't make sense). Thanks!