# Type inference from enum with ORM-like model

Tags: typescript

I have an `enum DataType { NUMBER, STRING }` and an object `const example: Record<string, DataType> = { id: DataType.NUMBER, name: DataType.STRING }`.

I would like the TypeScript to understand that `example.id` is a `number` (instead of `DataType.NUMBER`), and the same with `example.name` being seen as `string` instead of `DataType.STRING` through a generic `converter()` function.

It's not necessary to implement the function, just the `type` inference according to the passed argument for it:

```
function converter(...): infer type here { ... }

const example = converter({ id: DataType.NUMBER, name: DataType.STRING });

ts.typeof example.id === number
ts.typeof example.name === string
```

My goal is that the user should pass a data model ("schema") and the function will return a value compatible with the data model, similar to an ORM.

```
class Model {
    public get(... columns: string[]) {
        // ...
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public columns: {
        id: DataType.NUMBER,
        name: DataType.STRING,
        age: DataType.NUMBER
    }
}

const user = new User.get("id", "name")

ts.typeof user === { id: number, name: string }
```

---

**Edit #1:** as a complement, in reality, I can get the result easily like this:

```
function convert<T extends Record<string, DataType>>(schema: T) {
     return {} as ConvertedType = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends DataType.NUMBER ? number : T[K] extends DataType.STRING ? string : never };
}
```

And although it works fine, it doesn't work in more complex codes like:

```
interface Schema {
  [k: string]: DataType
}

type SchemaReturn<S extends Schema, C extends keyof S> = {
    [K in C]: S[K] extends DataType.NUMBER ? number : S[K] extends DataType.STRING ? string : never;
};

abstract class Model {
  public schema: Schema = {};
  
  public select<C extends keyof this["schema"]>(... columns: C[]) {
    return {} as SchemaReturn<typeof this["schema"], C>;
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  public schema = {
    id: DataType.NUMBER,
    name: DataType.STRING,
    age: DataType.NUMBER
  }
}

const user = new User;
const data = user.select("id", "name");

data.id; // Must be `number` but got `never`
data.name; // Must be `string` but got `never`
```

Comment: This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75065191), however, as it deals with new elements, I decided to create a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

I got a result very close to what I would like, despite having replaced the `enum` by a `const` and generating a certain "strangeness" in the type of the `schema` property:

```
const DataType = {
  NUMBER: 0,
  STRING: 1,
} as const;

interface Schema {
  [k: string]: typeof DataType[keyof typeof DataType];
}

type SchemaReturn<S extends Schema, C extends keyof S> = {
  [K in C] 
    : S[K] extends typeof DataType.NUMBER ? number
    : S[K] extends typeof DataType.STRING ? string
    : never;
};

class User extends Model {
  public schema = {
    // And here are the odd ones:
    id: DataType.NUMBER, // ts.typeof id === 0 (but expected to keeped DataType.NUMBER)
    name: DataType.STRING, // ts.typeof id === 1 (but expected to keeped DataType.STRING)
    age: DataType.NUMBER, // ts.typeof id === 0 (but expected to keeped DataType.NUMBER)
  };
}

// ...
// But here I get exactly the result I would like:
data.id; // ts.typeof data.id === number
data.name; // ts.typeof data.name === string
```

I am open to new suggestions since I would like to keep working with `enum` instead of JS `const`.